# Prove that if $f$ is analytic on the domain $D := \{0 < |z| < 1\}$ and $|f(z)| \leq 1$ then the limit of $f$ at $0$ exists.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $f$ is analytic on the domain $D := \{0 < |z| < 1\}$ and $|f(z)| \leq 1$ then the limit of $f$ at $0$ exists.

I tried for a long time to use the "$\epsilon,\delta$" definition to prove this, however I realised that I might be able to prove it much more easily. I split the proof into two cases.

Case 1: $f$ has no singularities at $0$. Then $f$ is analytic at $0$ and we're done.

Case 2: $f$ has a singularity at $0$. Then consider the domain $D$ as a deleted neighbourhood $N_0(0,1)$. It is given that $f$ is analytic on this neighbourhood, and also $f$ is bounded here. Therefore $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$, hence the limit at $0$ exists.

I have a couple of questions. Firstly, is the proof correct? And secondly, how would I expand the first case more given that it's not wrong? I'm not actually sure if it's correct, it just seemed intuitive however I have no idea how I would justify it.

Comment: "$f$ is analytic on this neighbourhood, and also $f$ is bounded here. Therefore $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$" Is it given? This one more or less you need to prove.

Comment: Well, its is given that $f$ is analytic on $D$. It is also given that $|f| \leq 1$ on $D$. Or do you mean that I should prove that boundedness and analyticity around a singularity implies that the singularity is removable?

Comment: How do you know that given this two facts, then it has a removable singularity? This is true, but are you allowed to use this?

Comment: @JakeReidBrowning I assume what John meant was: Do you have a theorem in your toolbox that allows the conclusion "bounded and analytic in a punctured disk $\implies$ the singularity is removable". - After all this tool is equivalent to the claim in a very shallow way

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Maybe I should explicitly show this.

Comment: Hint: Consider $g(z)=zf(z)$.